# Calculating probability that cars have defects

Tags: probability

"Minor defects are found on $7$ of $10$ new cars. If $3$ of the $10$ cars are selected at random, what is the probability that $2$ have minor defects?"

I don't understand why "$3C1 = 3$ ways of choosing $1$ non defective car of $3$" must be calculated to solve this problem. Can you explain?

From Barron's SAT Subject Test Math 2 book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you choose 3 cars at random where 2 cars are defective, you could have chosen the cars in the different possible orders

Defective car, Defective car, Good Car

or

Good Car, Defective car, Defective car

or

Defective car, Good Car, Defective car

There are three positions for the good car.

So if you pick 4 cars at random with 3 defective cars you could have

$_4C_3$ ways to choose.

Comment: No, it is not about the order of selection.  Order does not matter.  It's about selecting $1$ *from* $3$ non-defective cars.

Answer (score 0):

To count the favored case: There are ${^7\mathsf C_2}$ ways to choose $2$ from $7$ defective cars *and* ${^3\mathsf C_1}$ ways to choose $1$ of the $3$ non-defective cars.

To count the probability space: There are ${^{10}\mathsf C_3}$ ways to choose any $3$ from all $10$ cars.

Hence the probability for *your* question is: $\dfrac{{^7\mathsf C_2}{^3\mathsf C_1}}{^{10}\mathsf C_3}$

---

Consider a *similar* question.

> "Minor defects are found on $7$ of $10$ new cars. If$\underline{\;4\;}$of the $10$ cars are selected at random, what is the probability that $2$ have minor defects?"

The answer to *this* question is: $\dfrac{{^7\mathsf C_2}{^3\mathsf C_2}}{^{10}\mathsf C_4}$

Now are you seeing where the numbers come from?